# Jobs CV shows as on hold when complete

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-overflow-jobs

I have completely filled out my CV, yet the page says it is still on hold because I haven't added a complete work experience.

[image]

The problem is, I've added three. If "complete" indicates that the entries I've added are insufficient, I have no idea what makes them insufficient and the UI doesn't tell me that there is an issue when I edit them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have been working on refining the CV editor and we missed one of the edge cases. Thank you for reporting this, Tyrsius! This is fixed now.

Comment: I am still encountering this

Comment: @AndrewG.H. Make sure you have completed all the mentioned sections(_personal statement, tech you want to work with and either a complete education/experience record_) listed on the notification. If the notification still doesn't go away then post a new question marked as a bug explaining your scenario.

Comment: I have exactly same problem. does this bug still remains?