# Jobs completion is confusing

Tags: discussion, status-completed, stack-overflow-jobs

My Jobs profile is at 74% completion, and the UI doesn't tell me why.

[image]

I've added

- A personal statement
- Job Status
- Technology Tags
- Work Experience
- A stack exchange account
- Stack Exchange answers (3)
- Open Source links  (GitHub)
- A book
- Favorite Editor

This is only 3/4 done? How is this number being calculated?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The completion score considers various aspects of your CV. Once you complete the minimum requirements of your CV (*personal statement, tech you want to work with and one complete education/ work experience record*), we start showing you *Improve your CV* notification in the CV editor's sidebar which would give you a clear idea of what sections you should complete in order to reach a 100% completion score.

Unfortunately, there was a regression caused due to the issue that you spotted in your earlier bug report: [Jobs CV shows as on hold when complete](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/313101/jobs-cv-shows-as-on-hold-when-complete) because of which even though your CV was minimum complete you were still seeing an incorrect notification in the sidebar. Said issue is fixed. So, you should be able to see an *Improve your CV* sidebar notification now.

Comment: I do now see this, but I'm still [experiencing issues](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/313116/jobs-cv-shows-lack-of-education-as-error)