# Jobs CV shows lack of education as error

Tags: bug, stack-overflow-jobs

I know having no formal education isn't exactly common, but I didn't realize StackOverflow didn't consider me a developer without it. I have zero education entries, and "Improve your CV" tells me I have therefore not finished my Jobs CV, despite having multiple experience entries spanning 5 years.

Is this intentional?

[image]

Comment: It's a little misleading to call this an "error". It's a lack of completeness, that's all. (Completion scores are almost always impractical to fill up, in my experience, so this isn't terribly surprising.)

Comment: @NathanTuggy There should really be an option to say "None"

Comment: @NathanTuggy Some people (like me) really hate uncompleted forms. It's annoying. That's actually the whole point of "completion score". It makes people want to complete it.

Comment: @NathanTuggy Completion is obviously saying I am not done filling out the form yet, explicitly claiming that without education I have an unfinished CV. But if this is *not* an error, its kind of inconsiderate.